# Shrinkwrap modifier jagged edges when solidify modifier is applied

Tags: modifiers

I have added my mesh with the shrinkwrap modifier onto another mesh, and It's causing jagged edges when I add the solidify modifier.

[image]

here is the file if someone wants to take a look at it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to plane 02 a couple of holding loops.

[image]

Comment: That worked fine thank you.